# Need to connect DataStage with the SingleStore cloud db

Tags: datastage, singlestore

I tried creating a connection with the SingleStore cloud db, but IBM datastage isn't able to connect. Have added all the necessary details like hostname, port, username and password and still is not able to connect to the SingleStore.

Tried connecting datastage with singlestore cloud db but is not able to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Infosphere datastage 11.7.1.4 and works fine.

You need to add 3 steps :
1- Review the firewall inbound and outbound in the Singlestore portal. add the engine ip
2- Add the url info is JDBC connector like:
jdbc:singlestore://:/?user=&password=
3- add in "JDBC driver classpath" the library ubication like: $APT_ORCHHOME/../../ASBNode/lib/java/singlestore/singlestore-jdbc-client-1.1.9.jar
4- Add value in "JDBC driver classname", put com.singlestore.jdbc.Driver

regards!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!